# Get a Service Definition in a Symfony2 ContainerAwareCommand

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm trying to get a Service Definition in a ContainerAwareCommand as per http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html#getting-and-setting-service-definitions

However, this immediately results in a failure:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method appDevDebugProjectContainer::getDefinition()

I couldn't find much more in the docs about this behaviour, any ideas?

EDIT: Code example:

```
class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {

    protected function execute(InputInterface $p_vInput, OutputInterface $p_vOutput) {
        try {
            var_dump($this->getContainer()->getDefinition('api.driver'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            print_r($e);
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, can you provide the bunch of code you wrote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In example that you provided `$container` is not instance of `Container` class, but `ContainerBuilder` class. Container has not any method named `getDefinition()`.

I can't say much more if you don't show context where you want use that definition.

**edit:**

Below I've posted example of code using `ContainerBuilder`. It's copied directly from symfony's command, so I guess it's good example of use.

```
// Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ContainerDebugCommand.php

/**
 * Loads the ContainerBuilder from the cache.
 *
 * @return ContainerBuilder
 */
private function getContainerBuilder()
{
    if (!$this->getApplication()->getKernel()->isDebug()) {
        throw new \LogicException(sprintf('Debug information about the container is only available in debug mode.'));
    }

    if (!file_exists($cachedFile = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('debug.container.dump'))) {
        throw new \LogicException(sprintf('Debug information about the container could not be found. Please clear the cache and try again.'));
    }

    $container = new ContainerBuilder();

    $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator());
    $loader->load($cachedFile);

    return $container;
}
```

Best!

Comment: Great answer, works as expected. Can you elaborate on why this returns something different than ContainerAwareCommand->getContainer()?

Comment: I'm not sure if understood your question above, but Container class is different than ContainerBuilder one. ContainerAwareCommand->getContainer() return object of class Container. You need ContainerBuilder so you have to act like in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression that the Container also had the capability to get a Definition!